# PHP exception and user message

Tags: php, exception

I have a project object.
A user can assign a worker object for it.

99% of the case the project object has all the proper fields set.
In some cases, the project is missing a field.

In order for a worker to be assign to a project the project must have all the required fields setup.

To solve this, I throw exceptions like this: ( don't try to find a pattern here, the real example is more complex )

```
if ($project->startDate == false ) {
  throw new Exception("Missing startDate attribute for project id: $id");
}


if ($project->finishDate == false ) {
  throw new Exception("Missing finishDate attribute for project id: $id");
}

if ($project->startDate > $project->finishDate ) {
  throw new Exception("Invalid start date for project id: $id");
}
```

The problem with this is that I need to display a custom message to the user each time. For example if the first error is thrown the user should see: 'Please setup the project start date' and so on.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just define your own exception class and your whole code in a [`try .. catch`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

```
class FormException extends Exception {
   private var $userMessage;
   public function __construct($message, $userMessage) {
     parent::__construct($message);
     $this->userMessage = $userMessage;
   }
   public function getUserMessage() {return $this->userMessage;}
}

try {
  // Whole code goes here, probably a function call
  throw new FormException("Missing startDate attribute for project id: $id",
                          'Please setup the project start date');
} catch (FormException $e) {
  echo $e->getUserMessage();
  error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

By the way, if you want to include variable contents in a string, either use double quotes (`"id: $id"`) or concatenate (`'id: ' . $id`).

Comment: I already throw and exception. The problem is I need to display different thing for each case. Also I can't change the message because I will log it to error_log, and I need the technical information.

Comment: @danip I'm sorry, but this code does exactly what you describe. It displays the argument you created the exception object with. If you want to log the error, just call [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) instead of `echo`.

Comment: My problem is a bit more abstract: how to throw a technical error message ( that can be use in an error log ) and how to give the user different friendly messages for each case.

Comment: @danip Oh, you should've stressed that in the question. Does the updated version solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try
{
  $Message = '';
  if ($project->startDate == false ) {
    $Message = "Please setup the project start date\n";
    throw new Exception("Missing startDate attribute for project id: $id");
   }


   if ($project->finishDate == false ) {
     $Message = "Please setup the project finish date\n";
     throw new Exception("Missing finishDate attribute for project id: $id");
   }

   if ($project->approved == false ) {
     $Message = "Please setup the project approved field\n";
     throw new Exception("Missing approved attribute for project id: $id");
   }
}
catch(Exception $Ex)
{
   // Log in some way you like the $Ex-getMessage();
   echo nl2br($Message);
}
```

Comment: The error message is to technical for the user. I need to display a different friendly user message for each case and use the exception message for logging.

Comment: What about finish date ? the echo will say start date

Comment: @danip This is not true since the $Message will be echoed only in the case you lanch an Exception. In all the case, you'll echo something.

Comment: yes you're right, I missed that. I think this is what I need. But what if I have to wrap the logic in a function ?

Comment: so the try/catch block will only have something like this: try { $project->SetWorker();} catch (Exception $objEx) { } . How to I get the user message ?

Comment: @danip Put a 'return TRUE' after the last if in the try and 'return $Message' in the catch.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4296/discussion-between-danip-and-aurelioderosa)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your project class, create a new method, probably called `getErrorMessage`.

That function should do the checks (no need to have the concrete way of validation outside of project or create a validation object for project). Then:

```
if ($message = $project->getErrorMessage())
{
    throw new Exception(sprintf('%s (project id: %d)', $message, $id));
}
```

If you decide to not throw exceptions for design reasons, this still is of use.

You gain more flexibility with a validator object that can naturally provide more detailed information than a single method. So it might be the better thing to do:

```
class ProjectValidator
{
    private $project;
    private $errors;
    public function __construct($project)
    {
        $this->project = $project;
    }
    public function isValid()
    {
        // run your checks, add errors to the array as appropriate.

        $errors = array();

        if (!$this->project->startDate)
        {
            $errors[] = 'Missing startDate attribute';
        }

        if (!$this->project->finishDate)
        {
           $errors[] = 'Missing finishDate attribute';
        }

        if (!$this->project->approved)
        {
            $errors[] = 'Missing approved attribute';
        }

        $this->errors = $errors;

        return (bool) count($this->errors);
    }
    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}

$validator = new ProjectValidator($project);
if (!$validator->isValid())
{
    // throw an exception or do whatever you want in case it's not valid

    $errors = $validator->getMessages();
    $message = sprintf("Project id: %d has the following %d error(s):\n", $id, count($errors));        
    foreach($errors as $index => $error)
    {
        $message .= sprintf("%d. %s\n", $index+1, $error);
    }

    throw new Exception($message);
}
```

Comment: Your solution is interesting. But I'm looking for a generic solution. Something like custom exception classes. Creating validators for each object ( i have more then 100 ) seems a bit to much.

Comment: You can use inheritance and parameters to generalize validators (e.g. one validator could validate all your objects, just checking for the class and then), take [a look into symfony2 for a good example](http://www.symfony.com/) of real-world design of such. You can do custom exception classes as well, sure. However, I'm pretty sure you won't need more than one own Exception class in your scenario.